# How to read attributes in pyQGIS and QGIS 1.8 without setSelectedFeature

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I add a vector layer to a map with

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(self.vlayer)
```

later the attributes are read with

```
def select_all(layer):
layer.select([])
layer.setSelectedFeatures([obj.id() for obj in layer])
```

and

```
layer = self.vlayer
select_all(layer)
dict={}

for elem in layer.selectedFeatures():
    attrs = elem.attributeMap()
    for (k,v) in attrs.iteritems():
        dict.update({k:v})
```

The problem is that it selects all the feature in the map, too (which highlights them yellow). I tried to use

```
layer = self.vlayer
layer.select()
dict={}

for elem in layer:
   attrs = elem.attributeMap()
    for (k,v) in attrs.iteritems():
        dict.update({k:v})
```

but i get only an empty dictionary. Is it possible to get the values without selecting everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to select any of the features on the map.  This is all you need to loop over all the features in a layer with all their attributes:

```
layer = self.vlayer
provider = layer.dataProvider()
layer.select(provider.attributeIndexes())
for feature in layer:
   print feature.attributeMap()
```

There are few overloaded calls to `select()` this is the one you need to use http://qgis.org/api/1.8/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a13c6551c0b96da88004904d584599185

**Note**: This `select()` method has been removed from QGIS 2.0 and is replaced with:

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    print feature
```

Comment: `attributeMap()` returns a `dict` of `field index : value`

Comment: Ok thanks. It is working. Had a little mistake in the code.